# Translator before editor in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I'm citing a work with `biblatex-chicago` notes style, and the `editor` label appears before the `translator`. I would like it the other way around since this is how this work is cited other places, and the translation was the more notable work in this case (from Latin to English).

Here's my .bib entry:

```
@book{syntagma3,
title={Syntagma Musicum III},
author={Michael Praetorius},
publisher={Oxford University Press},
location={Oxford},
date={2004},
%origdate={1619},
translator={Kite-Powell, Jeffery T.},
editor={Kite-Powell, Jeffery T.},
keywords={Primary}
}
```

I get this:

> Praetorius, Michael. Syntagma Musicum III. Edited and translated by Jeffery T. Kite-Powell. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2004.

but I want this:

> Praetorius, Michael. Syntagma Musicum III. Translated and edited by Jeffery T. Kite-Powell. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2004.

I would like that order in citations as well. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Fussner, the creator of `biblatex-chicago`, was able to help me add some custom bibliography strings and create a custom editor type to solve my problem.

This is preferable because `windycity` does not support listing multiple editors, which I needed for another source.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{syntagma3,
  title={Syntagma Musicum III},
  author={Michael Praetorius},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
  location={Oxford},
  date={2004},
  %origdate={1619},
  editor={Kite-Powell, Jeffery T.},
  editortype={trev},
  keywords={Primary}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{bytrev,cbytrev}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bytrev = {translated and revised by},%
  cbytrev = {trans\adddotspace and rev\adddot},}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{syntagma3}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `windycity` now supports multiple editors with a [recent change](https://github.com/brianchase/windycity/commit/a0903ebf2a3cd64133218f1e3ebcb2507c954234)

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to switch to the `windycity` style. This is a newer Chicago style and seems to offer better flexibility and adherence to *CMOS* than `biblatex-chicago`.

The option `swaptrans` does what you want. From the manual:

> **swaptrans**=*true*, *false*                 default: `false`
>
> According to *CMOS*, if a work has an editor and a translator, their
> names should appear in citations in the order in which they appear on
> the work’s title page (see CMOS 14.104). By default, the style lists
> editors first. Entries with the option *swaptrans* reverse this order:
> Their translators print first. If a work’s translators and editors are
> the same, *swaptrans* reverses the order of their roles, say, from
> *edited and translated by* to *translated and edited by*. The same goes for compilers, revisers, and updaters, which the style treats as
> specialized editors. For more information, see section 3.2.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{syntagma3,
  title={Syntagma Musicum III},
  author={Michael Praetorius},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
  location={Oxford},
  date={2004},
  %origdate={1619},
  translator={Kite-Powell, Jeffery T.},
  editor={Kite-Powell, Jeffery T.},
  options={swaptrans},
  keywords={Primary}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=windycity]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{syntagma3}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks! That does indeed accomplish what I wanted. There are some other differences between these two styles that I will have to try to solve now (in shorthand entries of the same source, it lists the title each time instead of just the author, and some of the entries are out of order for chapters in books). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Found the short `short` option for the first problem